# jquery tooltip prevents another script from working

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip, conflict

Problem: When I activate jQueryUI tooltip it prevents another script on the page from working.
Description: I have a floating button on a page:

```
<div id="buttonTOC">
<a href="#" id="buttonText" title="Click to open and close the Table of Contents"> Table Of Contents</a>
</div><!-- End button <div> -->
```

This is used by the following script to open a hidden div:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("div#buttonTOC").click(function() {
      $("div#table-of-contents").animate({height:'toggle'},500);       
    });
});
```

This works correctly but if I add a script to use tooltips then it stops functioning and nothing happens on click. The tooltip does work as expected.
I've tried some experiments to get this working including the following attempt to disable 'tooltip' on the div in question but this doesn't make any difference.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$( 'a#buttonText' ).tooltip({
    track: true
});
$('#buttonTOC *[title]').tooltip('disable');
});
```

I would suspect a conflict between the scripts but then again I assume that something like a tooltip would be able to work regardless of the presence of other scripts.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to implement this successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a typo:

```
$( 'p#buttonText' ).tooltip({
  track: true
});
```

It should be `a#buttonText`, not `p`

Aside from that, there seems to be no problem with the script.

Comment: Thanks. I double checked to make sure that wasn't the problem and its not. Still doesn't work with the tooltip script activated.